# Problem with SSL WIldcard Certificate on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

Firstly I had working custom subdomain for my appservice.

Then I bought SSL wildcard Certificate and then generated pfx file with password. Next I uploaded certificate using Upload Certificate under Private Key Certificates. Certificate has Health Status = Healthy.

Finally, under binding tab I added TLS/SSL binging for my custom domain, choosen this certificate and its type = SNI SSL. Everything seems to be fine, undet custom domain there is SSL State = Secure and SSL Binding = SNI SSL.

When I go to my website - there is no information about any certificates.
I also tried the same with Create App Service Managed Certificate - the same effect, status Healthy, but certificate does not appear on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

@mateuszwdowiak It sounds like you successfully added the SSL binding.

There are two main issues that I can think of that might have proceed the unexpected results that you encountered. Firstly, it can take some time for the SSL certificates to propagate out across the web. From my experience, I've seen it take up to 3 hours. Just because the Azure portal says it's binded, does not mean it will be getting served up just yet.

Secondly, I've seen browser cache also come into play.

It's been a few days but I wanted to see if you resolved this issue. If not, can you please try re-binding your wild card cert, wait up to 3 hours, and then using a fresh browsing session, attempt to browse your site. This should resolve the matter. If not, please reply back so we can assist you further.